# Transpose column value as unique column header more like matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

As newbie to python trying to understand how i can achieve below transformation:

```
Date      Name   Value
20180101   Dto    801
20180102   Dto    80
20180101   Rnc    501
20180102   Rnc    50
```

to

```
           Dto     Rnc
20180101   801     501
20180102   501     50
```

Comment: Please explain the logic behind the transformation in more details. Do you actually mean `Rnc` in the second column of the bottom row in the input, and `80` in the second column of the bottom row of the output? If so, then it makes sense; if not, please explain.

Comment: yes..my bad.Corrected it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input and desired output are inconsistent, I assuming that's a typo.

Assuming you are using Pandas, you can use [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) to transform your data:

```
print(df)

       Date Name  Value
0  20180101  Dto    801
1  20180102  Dto     80
2  20180101  Rnc    501
3  20180102  Rnc     50

res = pd.pivot_table(df, index='Date', columns='Name', values='Value', aggfunc='first')

print(res)

Name      Dto  Rnc
Date              
20180101  801  501
20180102   80   50
```

Comment: Thanks @jpp.This helps.